# wiki page edit link doesn't work

Tags: 2013, wiki-pages, edit-form

I can create a blog post in Sharepoint 2013 without a problem. However, if I click on 'edit this page' next to the blog author, I get an error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 

Date and Time: 12/1/2014 5:02:31 PM
```

I've never seen a correlation ID of 0's

If I go to the Ribbon > Edit, the edit page loads fine.

Comment: Is this on premise or Office 365? If on prem, have a look at the ULS Logs. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463595(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I did look at the logs, and didn't see anything with that correlation OD